# java.lang.classcastexception: java.lang.long cannot be cast to java.lang.integer

Tags: glassfish

i had a exception that is very familiar, but i faced with this exception anormally.

My application was running well in **glassfish 3.1** server, then i migrated my application to **glassfish 3.1.2**. server. I deployed this successfully to new server.

When i opened my application, i got an exception that java.lang.classcastexception: java.lang.long cannot be cast to java.lang.integer.

Firstly, i thought that the exception appears due to **ojdbc6.jar** then i changed this with **ojdbc14.jar**. I restarted the server, but nothing changed. I get the same error. Now, i dont know what i have to do.

The code is:

```
geriDonecek.setToplamListeBuyuklugu((Integer)criteria2.setProjection(Projections‌​.rowCount()).uniqueResult());
```

Pls help me, I will be very glad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code it is throwing the exception on. Otherwise how can we possibly help?

Comment: geriDonecek.setToplamListeBuyuklugu((Integer)criteria2.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()); Exception is thrown on this code. The parameter type of setToplamListeBuyuklugu is int.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Long.intValue()` function to transform your long into integer.

`criteria2.setProjection(Projections‌​.rowCount()).uniqueResult().intValue())` should work

Comment: Thak you, but uniqueResult() has not intValue() property. This code was running in before glassfish server. I dont understand, what does that change. Now it throws exception.

Comment: Try int value= Integer.parseInt(criteria2.uniqueResult().toString()), what does it give you?

Comment: I did it just like you wrote and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: so I pick "long cannot be dereferenced" or "no suitable method found for intValue(long)" how about the requirement to have your primitive as close as you can to your cast (no spaces)...that's what solved it for me.